# What is the max latitude and longitude values possible?

Tags: latitude-longitude

What is the max value of latitude and longitude values possible available that fit on with in the world coordinate system.

Comment: ummm `90 to -90` and `180 and -180`? Is there more to this question?

Comment: Technically, only the poles are limited.  It's valid to have a longitude of 721 degrees (1 degree east of the prime meridian), and some systems use [0,360] to center on the Pacific Ocean.

Answer (score 3):

GIS systems with +/- 180 limits to longitude have problems with the meanderings of the International Date Line.  For example the Aleutians and Chukotka Peninsula both cross the 180th Meridian.  The Diomede Islands are at about 169W, so Siberia extends a considerable distance beyond 180.